# limit of solution of a autonomous differential equation at infinitive is a stationary point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$x(t)$ is a solution of $x'(t)=f(x)$ with domain of $(0,\infty)$ for $t$ and assume $x_0 \in \mathbb{R^n}$ and limit of $x(t)$ at infinite is $x_0$. Show that $f(x_0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f(x_{0})=c\neq0$ and suppose WLOG $c_{i}>0$ for some component $1\leq i\leq n$.  Then because $x(t)\to x_{0}$ as $t\to\infty$, we have $x_{i}'(t)\to c_{i}>0$ as $t\to\infty$, since $x\in\mathcal{C}^{1}$.  But then there exists a $T>0$ such that if $t\geq T$ we have $x_{i}'(t)>0$.  This precludes the possibility of $x_{i}(t)\to x_{0}^{i}$, and thus the possibility of $x(t)\to x_{0}$ as $t\to\infty.$  Therefore, $f(x_{0})=0$.

Comment: I would add in more details that then $x_i^\prime(t)> c_i-\epsilon>0$ for $t>T$ and  $x_i(t)=x(T)+\int_T^t x^\prime(t) dt \ge x(T)+(c_i-\epsilon)(t-T) \to \infty$

Comment: Can we prove this without the continouty of $f$. It is obvious that by darbox theorem f can only have discontinouty of second kind.